# oracle to PostgreSQL at scheduled time

Tags: postgresql, oracle10g, odoo

i want a program that transfer a set of data from a oracle to PostgreSQL at specific time (every 24 copy the new rows from oracle to PostgreSQL) is there any program or script that do this ...
i want to use it in moving data of a fingerprint reader (RFID) which use oracle database to openERP attend module so it make HR life easier...

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a fully integrated solution you can use something like [Talend](http://www.talend.com/products/data-integration) (or if you've got Microsoft SQL Server anywhere in your enviornment, SSIS can do it as well).

From the sound of it though, I'd be tempted to use a simple cron job that uses SQL*Plus to save the new rows to a data file, and then uses PSQL to load that database into Postgres.

Comment: Keep yesterdays_row_count in OpenERP. 
New_rows_count=(select count(*) from Oracle) - yesterday_row_count. 
Select top new_rows_count * into OpenERP from Oracle order by id desk. 
Now you need to process these Oracle rows into your hr tables.